# Any ideas on why NSArray response is not copying into another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Here is my code.

```
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myApp getCampaigns:^(NSArray *response) {
     [self.array addObjectsFromArray:response];
}];
```

if I use NSlog for response it shows two items in the array but when I use NSLog for Array it shows that the array is null..

**edit**

Declaration of the array.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Comment: Check that self didn't get nilled out.

Comment: You are right. I created a new array and it worked. How can I get it to work with the property?

Comment: Please show the declaration of the array property.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
[self.array addObjectsFromArray:response];
```

to

```
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:response];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
self.array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
MyViewController *vc = self;
[MyApp getCampaigns:^(NSArray *response) {
    [vc.array addObjectsFromArray:response];
}];
```

This will allow the objective-c compiler to create a strong reference to vc in  the block, which will then point to self.